# Can we set permission using eosjs?

Tags: eosjs, permissions

Using `cleos`, we can set the permissions like this:

```
cleos set account permission <your-account> active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "<your-key>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":<contract-account>,"permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p <your-account>
```

But can we do the above operation using `eosjs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, pull the existing permission, change only what you need to change, then pass everything back to updateauth ..

```
async function getNewPermissions(accountName) {
  const account = await eos.getAccount(accountName)
  const perms = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(account.permissions))
  return perms
}


const perms = await getNewPermissions(accountName)
console.log('New permissions =>', JSON.stringify(perms))
const updateAuthResult = await eos.transaction(tr => {

      for(const perm of perms) {

         tr.updateauth({
             account: accountName,
             permission: perm.perm_name,
             parent: perm.parent,
             auth: perm.required_auth
         }, {authorization: `${accountName}@owner`})

     }
})


console.log('Success =>', JSON.stringify(updateAuthResult));
```

I hope this will help. Thank You.

Comment: Is it possible to call the create permission action: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/authorization_manager.cpp#L179 directly? I'm pretty sure this is how cleos is doing it.

Answer (score 2):

In https://github.com/LimeChain/eoslime (uses eosjs behind the scene) there is a `addPermission` method, which you can use in order to accomplish your aim. It will add a permission for example `eosio.code` to your `active` authority.